# Trying to build websocket++ with MinGW: last few linker errors -- what could it be?

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, linker, mingw

Attempting to build [websocket++](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp) for Windows.

```
g++ -Wall -O2  -I/c/boost/boost_1_52_0//boost chat_server.o chat.o -o chat_server -L/c/boost/boost_1_52_0//stage/lib ../../libwebsocketpp.a /c/boost/boost_1_52_0//stage/lib/libboost_system-mgw46-mt-1_52.a c/boost/boost_1_52_0//stage/lib/libboost_date_time-mgw46-mt-1_52.a c/boost/boost_1_52_0//stage/lib/libboost_program_options-mgw46-mt-1_52.a c/boost/boost_1_52_0//stage/lib/libboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_52.a /c/boost/boost_1_52_0//stage/lib/libboost_regex-mgw46-mt-1_52.a -lpthread -lws2_32 -lmswsock
chat_server.o:chat_server.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6detail17sp_counted_impl_pINS_6threadEE7disposeEv[boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::thread>::dispose()]+0x14): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6threadD1Ev'
chat_server.o:chat_server.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost14checked_deleteINS_6threadEEEvPT_[void boost::checked_delete<boost::thread>(boost::thread*)]+0x11): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6threadD1Ev'
chat_server.o:chat_server.cpp:(.text$_ZN11websocketpp4role6serverINS_8endpointIS1_NS_6socket5plainENS_3log6loggerEEEE12start_listenERKN5boost4asio2ip14basic_endpointINSB_3tcpEEEj[websocketpp::role::server<websocketpp::endpoint<websocketpp::role::server, websocketpp::socket::plain, websocketpp::log::logger> >::start_listen(boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp> const&, unsigned int)]+0x307): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6thread12start_threadEv'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [chat_server] Error 1
```

Don't mind the double-slashes in the paths, it's from me being sloppy editing makefiles.

I had to compile boost 1.52 using MinGW also.

The linker can't seem to find `boost::thread` and `boost::thread::start_thread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get the websocket++ project compiled by using Mr. Lavavej's MinGW package (which comes with boost out of the box). I'm sure I could get it rolling from vanilla MinGW, too, by being a bit more methodical about dealing with boost... Turned out the `g++` i was originally using came from the strawberry perl dir.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like boost wants to link to the DLL version of the `boost::thread` library.  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/build.html for the rather convoluted documentation on how boost can/should be configured to use static or dynamic libraries for `boost::thread`.

You should be able to solve your problem by linking to the DLL version of the library instead of the static version.  You might also be able to solve your problem by defining `BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB` when compiling to configure the use of the static thread lib.  However I'm not sure whether or not the MinGW compiler supports the automatic tss cleanup that the static library relies on to clean up properly when threads exit.

Comment: I do have two versions of each library that got built (the static and dynamic) but they're all `.a` libraries. No DLL's were made when I built boost. Thanks for pointing out the macro that can hopefully do it, I'll try that too.